# Adding commands to the Problem and Terminal views context menus

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating an extension that adds commands to the context menus of the Problems and Terminal views. The Idea is that a user could right click on a selected Problem or highlighted text in Terminal and send that text to a website to search.

Is this functionality possible?
Or is there another menu key I should be using?

With the following code, nothing is added to the context menus:

```
"menus": {
      "view/item/context": [
        {
          "when": "true",
          "command": "textsearch.ProblemsStackOverflowSearch"        
        },
        {
          "when": "activePanel == workbench.panel.markers",
          "command": "textsearch.ProblemsUsaaWikiSearch"
        }
      ]
    }
```

However if I change "view/item/context" -> "view/title", the commands do appear in the title bar of the views.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to add a command to the terminal context menu as of vscode v1.83 Stable, see [Release Notes: terminal menus](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83#_contribute-to-terminal-menus).

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "terminal/context": [
        { "command": "terminalTest.sendText" }
      ],
      "terminal/title/context": [
        { "command": "terminalTest.sendText" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is still no Problems view context menu contribution exposed though.